# Как генерировать случайно распределенный величины по нормальному закону?

Tags: c#, статический-анализ

Как генерировать случайно распределенный величины по нормальному закону от 0 до 10?

Желательно сразу на c#, но можно и просто объяснить смысл =)

Comment: Метод обратной функции. Берутся случайные числа от [0;1] распределенные равномерно и подставляются как аргумент в функцию обратную необходимой функции плотности вероятности. Значение обратной функции и есть искомое случайное число.

Comment: Это все хорошо, но у меня еще есть корреляции, то есть мне надо сгенерировать 16 коррелирующих значений =)

Comment: Как они могут коррелировать друг с другом если они из одной выборки? Может надо посчитать автокорреляционную функцию для сгенерированной выборки?

Comment: Это шкалы тестирования, почему бы им не коррелировать друг с другом?
Корреляцию между двумя выборками то все просто, а тут именно есть результат тестирования, 16 шкал.

Answer (score 1):

[Stand-alone C# code for Φ(x)](http://www.johndcook.com/csharp_phi.html).